Talend ESB / Karaf : Get datasource from CamelContext / registry
so first I'm new to Talend ESB, Camel and Karaf and I'm facing an issue when I try to get a datasource (that has been created on a Karaf instance).
Here is the DataSources GBMREFPPR, is the one I'm trying to use.

I'm trying to get the connection using a java Bean like this :
try {
    DataSource source = (DataSource) camelcontext.getRegistry().lookupByName("GBMREFPPR");
    con = source.getConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

And when the route starts I get a java NullPointerException.
So is what I am trying to do is possible, and if so what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks.

You should ask the commercial vendor Talend to get help with their product.

The issue is that we use an older version (v7.3.1) of the Talend ESB Open Studio so we don't have access to it.
